# How to clone collection of unknown type?

Tags: java, generics, interface, clone

Suppose I have collection, stored in

```
Collection<V> member;
```

or in

```
C member;
```

How to clone this class with also cloning this member?

Comment: Is `C` a generic type?

Comment: What do you mean with 'clone'? Copy the declaration-type? Copy the Collection? Deep-copy the Collection?

Comment: `Collection` doesn't support `clone()`, so since the base type doesn't support it I think you're out of luck.  It's best to plan ahead and make certain your code uses the right type to get the job done.  Two things come to mind: `collection.addAll()` will *copy*, not clone, a collection, which might be good enough.  And there's always reflection.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> How to clone this class with also cloning this member?

I assume you're overriding the `clone` method. So you could use the provided runtimeType of `member` to get a new instance:

```
public class MyObject<V, C extends Collection<V>> {

    private C member = ...;

    @Override
    public MyObject clone(){
        MyObject clone = new MyObject();
        if(member != null){
             try {
                  clone.member = member.getClass().newInstance();
                  clone.member.addAll(member);
             } catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ignore){}
        }

        // clone other properties

        return clone;
    }
}
```

But this is quite dirty because you can never ensure that `C` has a default constructor or as mentioned by @shmosel, the collection could even be imutable. E.g. the `addAll()` call fails.

To overcome the above dirty way you could require a `Supplier<C>` when creating an instance of `MyObject` that way you could create your own collections as you wish:

```
private final Supplier<C> factory;

public MyObject(Supplier<C> factory){
    this.factory;
}
```

And only create the `member` when it is first time used. By invoking `factory.get()`.

That way you safely create the `member` variable when cloning the object. But then there's still the case with the imutability which is probably the breaker of any approach to copy the values from the `member` to `clone.member`.

Comment: Or that it's mutable.

Comment: @shmosel exactly i'll put that into the answer